# What is the default password for the `tomcat7` user on my system?

Tags: password, users, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed Apache Tomcat 7 via

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

and without editing any configuration I can start and stop the service `tomcat7` successfully (`localhost:8080` shows me the "It works!" page).

The installation seems to have created a user `tomcat7` under which Tomcat runs. I would like to log in as that user (rather, switch to it using `su tomcat7`) but I don't know the password -- yet I never configured one.

What is the password for user `tomcat7`?

Comment: Why doing this. There is no reason.

Comment: @DnrDevil I don't believe that's correct - the passwords are in `/etc/shadow` encoded/encrypted, and system users do not have passwords associated with them typically as they're not standard login accounts.

Comment: @Info-Screen, I need to set up a virtual X server for a webapp... this would be the easiest way to make sure that the display is owned by the correct user.

Comment: @Gerli `chown` would work fine or just use `su`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there should be ***zero reason*** to login as the `tomcat7` user.  There's no logical use case for this, so therefore I'm not sure why you'd try and use it.

> You state in your question you want to set up a virtual X server for a webapp - you don't *need* to login as `tomcat7` to do this, though your question isn't "How can I launch a virtual X server for my web app as `tomcat7` without logging in", so don't expect help here with that in this question.

Having said this, it's likely that this is a **System User Account** and not an actual user; these users typically have no passwords associated with it, as it is designed to be used by system daemons and services, rather than users.  Therefore, you **cannot** login as that user as it isn't designed to be logged into by users - to use the user, you have to use `su` to switch user to it, and you have to do so as superuser or root or with `sudo`.  Also note that there's the option of setting a password, but it's ill-advised to do so, for that user.

---

## Option 1 (Recommended, and the Proper Way to do this): `su` as `sudo` or `root`/superuser

***You will need to have `sudo` power, or access to the `root` user to get this working with these instructions.***

*With `sudo`:*

```
sudo su tomcat7
```

*As `root` user:*

```
su tomcat7
```

---

## Option 2 (NOT RECOMMENDED, because it introduces security concerns and other issues): Set a password

***You will need to have `sudo` power, or access to the `root` user to get this working with these instructions, and it is VERY likely you will break things by doing this.  I HIGHLY RECOMMEND not doing this!***

Set a password.

*With `sudo`:*

```
sudo passwd tomcat7
[set a password with the prompts]
```

*As `root`:*

```
passwd tomcat7
```

Once the password is set, then you can just login to the user (either via SSH or the console directly).

Again, I **strongly recommend** that you *do not do this method* - this could break Tomcat7, and can actually put your system at  risk because someone can now brute-force the password and have access to the tomcat instance *as* the tomcat user itself.

---

To reiterate though: **there is no logical reason to need to login as the `tomcat7` user**.  Do so at your own risk as you can affect evilness on your system if you're not careful.

Comment: the Question was how to do it whitout `su`

Comment: @Info-Screen they can't, that's the problem.  There's no way to switch to the user without `su`, as system user accounts USUALLY do not have passwords so you can't direct-login as them anyways.

Comment: @Info-Screen to actually state otherwise, nowhere does the user ask how to NOT need `su` to do this.  They stated they would rather be able to `su` to it, if you read closely.

Comment: I didn't realise there could be accounts without passwords. That's useful information. I'll look into other ways of doing what I wanted, that's fine. `/etc/shadow` has the line `tomcat7:*:...` which I assume means it is a system user account.

Comment: @Gerli they're called 'system' accounts, and are usually used for system daemons (such as Apache or nginx which use `www-data` by default, or PostgreSQL db server, which uses `postgres`, or MySQL which uses `mysql`, etc.).  They don't typically have passwords because only system daemons and services tend to use them...

Comment: `sudo su tomcat7` doesn't seem to make me `tomcat7`, though (and `sudo su` + `su tomcat` neither). `whoami` still reports my own username... but I guess that's a new question.

Comment: @Gerli `getent passwd tomcat7`.  See if there's any output.  If there is, then the user exists, but perhaps login is disabled completely (i.e. `/bin/false` for shell).  If that's the case, then you can't sanely solve that - you shouldn't change the shell, and you shouldn't try and use that user.