# Can't switch to tomcat user after installing tomcat via apt

Tags: apt, users, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Tomcat 7 from the default repository with

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

It installed fine, I can start/stop the service `tomcat7` using `sudo service tomcat7 restart` etc. `localhost:8080` shows me the "It works!" page. I didn't install any other `tomcat` packages.

`cat /etc/default/tomcat7` reports

```
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7
```

However, if I try to `sudo su tomcat7` or `sudo su` + `su tomcat7`, I'm not switched to the tomcat user (`whoami` reports my username).

What do I have to do to be able to switch to the user `tomcat7`?

Comment: This question is related http://askubuntu.com/questions/723384/what-is-the-default-password-for-the-tomcat7-user-on-my-system/723385#723385

Comment: @Arronical ..... that's because I asked that question.

Comment: Ha! More coffee needed I think!

Answer (score 6):

Your tomcat7 user has no login shell, have a look at `/bin/false` in the output below

```
% grep tomcat /etc/passwd 
tomcat7:x:134:149::/usr/share/tomcat7:/bin/false
```

**and there is no need to switch your user**. To run a command as tomcat7 use

```
% sudo -u tomcat7 whoami
tomcat7
```

Comment: There is a need... I changed the `/bin/false` to `/bin/bash` and can switch to it now.